# Smarty OR statement

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

This is working:

```
{if $filter.id_key='68'}
```

This doesn't:

```
{if ($filter.id_key='68' || $filter.id_key='63')}
```

Not sure what's wrong here (tried also without the round brackets). There are plenty of examples of the same OR statement in the same file.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `{if $filter.id_key='68'}` you are assigning `68` to `$filter.id_key`, so it's always true. You should use double equal `==`:

```
{if ($filter.id_key == '68' || $filter.id_key == '63')}
```